# Color border input in red (twig)

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, twig

Hey guys I have a little problem I do not know why my input is not colored in red ... here is my code (should be simple but I don't see where my code is failing)

My html code (twig) :

```
{{ form_widget(form.value, {'attr': {'class': 'error_input'}}) }}
```

My css :

```
.error_input{
    border : 1px solid red;
}
```

ps : i am using Symfony 3.4

Comment: Your `error_input` might be overridden by something else. Check this first. If you do not have control over this you can do this: `border-color: 1px solid red !important;` although it is only to be used as last option mostly. Do not abuse the `!important` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok found ...

`.error_input{
    border : 1px solid red !important;
}`

But why is that not working without !important ... ?

Comment: Your CSS is overridden by something else. This could be a library/file that uses the same class name.

Comment: but when i name it with a random name : "error_input12345azerty" that still not working with !important